# Can I fight the Devil Beasts again if I flee from them the first time?

Tags: tales-of-xillia

In Bermia Gorge, I was exploring and ran into an entirely too large wasp that nearly wiped my party. I managed to escape and it disappeared. Later, I found out that it was one of the Six Devil's Beasts, bonus bosses that you can fight for really good equipment.  Will Folzam (the wasp) respawn if I come here later or did I just ruin my chance at getting a good weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, it will certainly respawn!  I've had that happen to me, too, and the first time you meet them, they're rather too strong for you to fight.  You can determine if they're a Devil Beast by listening to the dialog between your party members when you first fight them.  If they mention something about them having a weapon embedded in their body, you can safely assume they're a Devil Beast.

To make them respawn after escaping from them, just leave the area, and come back.

The weapons are decent, but not all that good, from what I can tell.  I got Leia's, and it was weaker than her current weapon by the time I got it.  They're worth a respectable amount of Grade, though.

Comment: In other games the Devil weapons start out weak but get stronger for every enemy you kill with it. This makes them fantastic weapons in ng+ but usually not very good in the first playthrough. It is possible this game works but I can not confirm.

Comment: @AdamP Really?  Interesting.  I'm a huge fan of Tales games, and I had no idea such things happened.

Comment: Here is a link to how they worked in ToS (warning spoilers if you haven't played it). I imagine they work similarly in Xillia but I have not looked into it as I would like to avoid spoilers. http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Devil's_Arms

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they respawn if you run. I make a habit of encountering, then fleeing from, each of the beasts so I can see their stats and plan a later run at them. I've confirmed by running by two of the beasts twice, after running away from them.

Answer (score 0):

The devil arms weapons get stronger after each enemy you kill after you "unlock" their true potential by defeating the Gold Mage Knight in the optional dungeon after the main storyline has been completed. They are only good for NG+